# which Layer should populate Concurrency and Task in N-Tier architecture pattern in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, n-tier-architecture

**Please if this question off-topic you can write in a comment to delete it later :)**

If i have a 3 Layers ( *.DLL's )

- DataAccessLayer.DLL
- BusinessLogicLayer.DLL
- UI Application ( WPF, WinForms, any technology)

In my application i make BusinessLogicLayer methods return **Task** and in UI Application i call await when i use a method from BusinessLogicLayer

I have misunderstanding the following:

- Which layer should support by Task or concurrency ( Back-End, Middle-were, Front )
- If i need to make reusable BusinessLogicLayer for other developers, where they can also forgot to use awaitable / async methods in UI Application Layer in next projects that handled to them. How to achieve awaitable methods in Middle were layer without need to write **await**'s in every UI Event ( Button_Click, for example ).
- How to make the DataAccessLayer only contains the concurrency and awaited in UI Layer without needs of using **await**, **async** keywords.

My simple code contains the following :

**DataAccessLayer.DLL** a single method

```
public void MoveNext()
{
    if (RecordCount == 0) return;
    Tables[0].Query.Criteria.Clear();
    Tables[0].Query.Sorting = $"ORDER BY {string.Join(" ASC, ", 
    Tables[0].Keys.Select(x => x.KeyID))} ASC";
    FetchDataBuffer();
}
```

**BusinessLogicLayer.DLL** now wrapped the method of dataaccess in simple manner

```
public Task MoveNext() => Task.Run(() => { EntryBase.MoveNext(); });
```

**UI Layer ( Any application or front-end provider in .NET )**

```
 private async void BtnNext_ItemClick(object sender, ClickEventArgs e)
 {
    await EntryLogic.MoveNext();
    DeserializeBuffer();
 }
```

As seen above the ***DeserializeBuffer*** method will not execute until the concurrency method ( ***MoveNext*** ) is finished.

What i need to make is get rid off ***await's*** keywords and ***async*** in UI layer.

> What i actually do is failed and don't know why this happen

**Scenario i try to make as following:**

- Convert the method type of DataAccessLayer from **void** to **Task**

  ```
     public Task MoveNext()
     {
        return Task.Run(() => { 
        if (RecordCount == 0) return;
        Tables[0].Query.Criteria.Clear();
        Tables[0].Query.Sorting = $"ORDER BY {string.Join(" ASC, ", 
        Tables[0].Keys.Select(x => x.KeyID))} ASC";
        FetchDataBuffer();
        });
       }
  ```
- Then call await in Middle-were layer BusinessLogicLayer

  public async void MoveNext() => await EntryBase.MoveNext();
- After that calling the MoveNext in UI Layer from Logic layer. i guess that will make it awaitable because it already declared await in middle-were layer. but actually the UI layer executes the next method simultaneously. so the exceptions thrown because off next method ( DeserializeBuffer) depending on previous method ( EntryLogic.MoveNext)

  ```
    private async void BtnNext_ItemClick(object sender, ClickEventArgs e)
    {
      EntryLogic.MoveNext();
      DeserializeBuffer();  // exception thrown   
       /* because EntryLogic.MoveNext 
       is still executing and not awaited */
    }
  ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "get rid off await's keywords and async in UI layer." - that's the opposite to the direction most people would be working in. Why do you believe this to be true?

Comment: i don't really know. i just need to find a way to make reusable layer for developers where they can forgot to insert it and bugs starts. what your opinion sir

Comment: if you use async/task in any layer, somewhere it has to be awaited, or you need to call `.Result`. UI layer is good for awaiting, you have to do it anyway if you don't want UI thread to freeze until the task is done

Comment: and why the next function in UI layer still executing without awaited the previous function ! its declared awaited in Middle-were layer. thats strange

Comment: Krzysztof Skowronek , Thanks, so the Task methods should be in DataAccess ? or Middle-were ?

Comment: If you return Task directly without awaiting from one layer to another, you may leak context. Having async calls in UI layer is actually good if already have async BLL methods.

Comment: *Everywhere*. `Tasks` should appear at *all* layers if the underlying work is inherently asynchronous.

Comment: I sincerely hope you do not have this cluttered around your code base: `public Task MoveNext() => Task.Run(() => { EntryBase.MoveNext(); });` otherwise just forget about async/await or refactor your code base to use native task based methods. Using Task.Run to wrap synchronous method calls is bad practice.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, but this mean there's two tasks will executes in one single method ( one in BLL, and one in DAL ) ?

Comment: The application not inherently asynchronous, so should i make DataAcessLayer cleared ! and no async, task inside it, and only the BusinessLogicLayer contains Task methods, and UI Layer awaited one ? is this true ? sorry for asking many things because i really leak the TPL .NET

Comment: Peter Bons, please explain more and give a good approach or a "Solution"

Comment: Create a new multi layered small solution without any task, async and await. If it works, then redo it with task, async and await all the way through. You would easily understand how it should be done.

Comment: Thanks guys, any good approaches are always welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What i need to make is get rid off await's keywords and async in UI layer.

This is exactly wrong. The UI layer is the only place where `async` and `await` **must** be used. And they do *have* to be used in that layer.

Your data access technology is unspecified, but from the code, I'm guessing it may be `DataTable`-based, which is problematic because `DataTable` is extremely old and does not support `async`. Note that [wrapping method bodies with `Task.Run` to "make them asynchronous" is an antipattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) - those are actually [fake-asynchronous methods](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html), not truly asynchronous.

If I'm wrong and your data-access technology *does* support `async`, then you should be able to make your DAL methods `async` without using `Task.Run`. Start at the *lowest* level (e.g., whatever methods `FetchDataBuffer` calls) and change them to the asynchronous equivalents. Then let `async` grow from there. Note that "letting async grow" means using `async Task`, not `async void`; [`async void` in the BLL is definitely an antipattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

But if I'm right and your DAL is using `DataTable`, then you need to decide whether to switch to a newer data-access technology. If this isn't something you can do right now, then I'd recommend keeping the existing DAL and BLL code and just adding `async`/`await` to the UI layer:

```
private async void BtnNext_ItemClick(object sender, ClickEventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Run(() => EntryLogic.MoveNext());
  DeserializeBuffer();
}
```

This is not an antipattern because we're using `Task.Run` to *invoke* a method - to move it off the UI thread. It's not *ideal*, since we're still using more threads than necessary, but an ideal solution would require true asynchronous data access. With this kind of compromise, your DAL and BLL are still blocking, so they have limited use outside of desktop UI applications.

Comment: Sir, you actually got it. answered it well. really thanks for your appropriate help, about the Data Access technology, yes i use DataTable because of filling the GridViews, the app i working with is full of dynamic everything must be at runtime ( creating tables, adding new fields ) so i guess Entity Framework will not working with me. can you please provide a newer data access technology which binding easily with grids (example Collecctions, Lists, etc, idk  ) , if you never mind provide some links for your well-written Task and asynchronous things in your blog to the answer you provide :)

Comment: There's nothing like `Fill` in the newer data access technologies; you end up having to build your own `ObservableCollection<T>`s and whatnot. Entity Framework is a fine approach, as is Dapper. None of the new ones are as simple as Data Tables, but none of them are as inefficient, either.

Comment: you mean that .NET became useless :)    The SQLDataReader has Async methods, so only the old datatable, datasets are old, please can you tell what is data-access technology is good for dynamic creating, adding new tables, fields at run-time.  i guess ObservableCollection<T> is hard to develop ! easy one is good one !

Comment: after reading some of your articles, found that Task.Run() is bad practice for ASP.NET applications. so that implementing Async, Task in UI only ? not in BLL is that true about what i got ?

Comment: @abtka: Yes; your best choices are to either update the DAL to a modern technology (that supports `async`), or to keep everything synchronous except the UI layer.